# Where is the .meteor directory in an app deployed by mup?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-up

I am using `mup` to deploy my Meteor app to AWS, but I can't find a `.meteor` folder on the server.

How I can find my meteor folder on AWS VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mup classic builds your meteor application and deploy it on your server on /opt//app

Mup is an abandoned project, that's why I forked it and built yamup (Yet Another Meteor Up), that you can find at https://github.com/bordalix/yamup

It works with the latest versions of Meteor and with Ubuntu up until 16.

Comment: While the original `mup` by arunoda was abandoned, there is a community maintained fork of `mupx` that is accepted by the community as its successor, available on [github](https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up) and is far from being abandoned.

Comment: @MasterAM mup by arunoda didn't use Docker, while mupx does. yamup sticks to the initial philosophy by not using Docker.

Answer (score 3):

Once you build your Meteor application, as `mup` (meteor-up) does, a bundle is created, and this bundle is a normal Node.js application.

Therefore, there is no `.meteor` directory within it, as well as all of the other development-time tools from the `meteor` CLI.